Measurement of construct confusion
What are the different ways of measuring a construct? I have three items for one construct. The three questions are derived from articles, and they are used commonly as items to measure the variable. I will be using this construct further for OLS regression. So, how will I get the value for the variable? Can I check for Cronbach's alpha and if its value is more than 0.7, is it ok to compute the average of the three items and use the value in regression?

Yes, using an average score is one approach. Another, and more rigorous, approach would be to use structural equation modeling (SEM)$^1$. SEM is a latent variable model, and has many advantages over the your approach. One advantage of particular note, is that it allows you to include your construct in a regression equation in a way that controls for measurement error.
All of this being said, your approach is not a bad one, especially considering your fairly high Cronbach's $\alpha$, though I would still look into SEM if you have the time.
$^1$See Lei & Wu (2007) for an accessible introduction to SEM. For a more comprehensive introduction, I recommend Kline (2023).
References
Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling. Guilford publications.
Lei, P. W., & Wu, Q. (2007). Introduction to structural equation modeling: Issues and practical considerations. Educational Measurement: issues and practice, 26(3), 33-43.

Thank you so much. I will surely look at the SEM approach. I wanted some kind of confirmation on the method that I used.
